# How to load data by id with @GetMapping

Tags: java, database, spring-mvc, cuba-platform

Hello sorry for my english, but could you help me please. I have two forms (list and edit list) How can I display an edit form based on the id on the list? I use version 6.8 and IDEA, also working in Portal Module. For the form I use Freemarker(Ftl).

Here is my POJO class:

```
private String _csrf;
@NotBlank
private String id;
@NotBlank
private String firstName;
@NotBlank
private String lastName;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String get_csrf() {
    return _csrf;
}
public void set_csrf(String _csrf) {
    this._csrf = _csrf;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Controller for adding and edditing:

```
@GetMapping("/add")
public String add(Model model) {
John john = new John();
model.addAttribute("john", john);
return "add";
}

@PostMapping("/add")

public String save(@ModelAttribute("john") John john) {
  String firstName = john.getFirstName();
  String lastName = john.getLastName();
  John newJohn = new John(firstName, lastName);

  John standardEntity = metadata.create(John.class);
  standardEntity.setFirstName(newJohn.getFirstName());
  standardEntity.setLastName(newJohn.getLastName());
  dataManager.commit(standardEntity);

  return "redirect:/allPersons";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/allPersons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPersons(Model model) {
  List<John> johns = dataManager.loadList(LoadContext.create(John.class)
        .setQuery(LoadContext.createQuery("select u from test6$John u")));
  List<JohnPojo> johnPojos = johns.stream().map(e -> {
    JohnPojo johnPojo = new JohnPojo();
    johnPojo.setFirstName(e.getFirstName());
    johnPojo.setLastName(e.getLastName());
    johnPojo.setId(e.getId().toString());
    return johnPojo;
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());

  model.addAttribute("users", johnPojos);
  return "list";
}
```

When i go to Url: @GetMapping("/update/{id}"), I want to return the edit form based on id with data and save it.
Could you please tell me which POST and GET method I should write to achieve the desired result. I am really struggling because there is lack of documentaion for this specific task. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where exactly you're stuck, but it seems you'll need to use your dataManager to load the entity. Something like:

```
@GetMapping("/update/{id}")
public String getForUpdate(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    John john = dataManager. load(id);
    model.addAttribute("john", john);
    return "update";
}
```

Comment: @Lvzerhawk , did you have the update.jsp page ? It should work

Comment: it does not recognize your load(id)

Comment: @Lvzerhawk, the above code is an example, not for copy/pasting. Your dataManager needs a method to retrieve objects based on ID, typically named load, get, read or similar.

Comment: Aight, Thank you!